# Dropdown onchange textarea enable and disable in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, select, onchange

This question already asked but that is not solving my issue.

I want to `enable` and `disable` `text-area` when `drop-down` change. I tried some code but showing error.

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'disabled' of undefined
>   at Scope.$scope.firstUsageChange (addcoupon.js:130)

**addcoupon.html**

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <label>First Usage<code>*</code></label>
    <select class="form-control" name="first_usage" ng-model="formData.first_usage" ng-change="firstUsageChange()" ng-required="true">
        <option value="">Select First Usage</option>
        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="no">No</option>
    </select> 
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <label>First Usage Title<code>*</code></label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="first_usage_title" ng-model="formData.first_usage_title"  ng-disabled="disabled" ng-required="true"></textarea>
</div>
```

**addcoupon.js**

```
$scope.firstUsageChange = function () {
    $scope.result = $scope.formData.first_usage;
    if($scope.result == 'yes')
    {
        $scope.first_usage_title.disabled= false;
    }
    else
    {
        $scope.first_usage_title.disabled= true;
    }
    //console.log();
};
```

Comment: use ng-disabled in your html `ng-disabled="first_usage_title.disabled"`

Answer (score 1):

in the html part:

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="first_usage_title" ng- 
model="formData.first_usage_title"  ng-disabled="disabled" ng-required="true"> 
</textarea>
```

try changing ng-disabled by:

```
ng-disabled="first_usage_title.disabled"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the result  i just change $scope data `$scope.disabled = true;`

```
$scope.firstUsageChange = function () {
    $scope.result = $scope.formData.first_usage;
    if($scope.result == 'yes')
    {
        $scope.disabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $scope.disabled = false;
    }
};
```